# Consulta como hacer subgrupos dentro de una columna

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo una consulta como creo un subgrupo dentro de una columna, por ejemplo tengo una columna asi:

```
index hr
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
... ...
17374   19
17375   20
17376   21
17377   22
17378   23
```

donde la columna llamada 'hr', son horas que van de 0 a 24 horas, pero quisiera agruparlo en subgrupos de 6 horas, es decir, que las horas que van de 0,1,2,3,4,5,6, ahora estan codificadas como numero 1. Luego las horas 7,8,9,10,11,12 sera codificada con numero 2, asi hasta tener solo 4 subgrupos.

Mi pregunta es como haria dicho codigo

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Estas utilizando `pandas`? Por favor edita tu pregunta e incluye algunas filas de tus datos como texto, no como imagen. ¿Qué has intentado? En este sitio no resolvemos tareas y/o proyectos. Para cada pregunta es necesario que agregues un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a generar un dataframe de ejemplo similar al que planteas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"hr": list(range(0, 24))*200})
```

Tiene esta pinta:

```
      hr
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
...   ..
4795  19
4796  20
4797  21
4798  22
4799  23
```

Creo que lo que buscas sería esto:

```
df["grupo"] = df.hr//6+1
```

simplemente se toma el número que hay en hr, se hace la división entera entre 6 (lo que produce un número entero entre 0 y 3) y se le suma 1. El resultado se asigna a una nueva columna llamada grupo. El dataframe se vería ahora así:

```
      hr  grupo
0      0      1
1      1      1
2      2      1
3      3      1
4      4      1
...   ..    ...
4795  19      4
4796  20      4
4797  21      4
4798  22      4
4799  23      4
```

Ahora ya podrías hacer un `.groupby("grupo")` para realizar las agregaciones que necesites. Por ejemplo, para contar cuántos valores de la columna hr hay en cada grupo:

```
df.groupby("grupo").count()
---
         hr
grupo      
1      1200
2      1200
3      1200
4      1200
```

Answer (score 1):

## Alternativa 1: DatetimeIndexResampler

Si estás trabajando con horas es más conveniente usar [`.resample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html). Este método te permite hacer agrupaciones cada N minutos, horas, días, meses, etc...

Puedes hacer los intervalos de la siguiente forma:

```py
dateIndex=pd.date_range(start='06/01/2022', end='06/02/2022 00:00:00',freq='1h')
```

Y asociar los datos a las fechas con:

```py
# data=pd.Series(__DATOS_AQUI__,index=dateIndex)
data=pd.Series(range(len(dateIndex)),index=dateIndex)
```

Se vería el *dataframe* así:

```
2022-06-01 00:00:00     0
2022-06-01 01:00:00     1
2022-06-01 02:00:00     2
2022-06-01 03:00:00     3
2022-06-01 04:00:00     4
2022-06-01 05:00:00     5
2022-06-01 06:00:00     6
...
2022-06-02 00:00:00    24
```

Para agrupar en grupos de 6 horas usamos `data.resample('6h')`, puedes aplicar una función de cómo quieres mostrar la agrupación.

```
data.resample('6h').agg(lambda p: p.values)
```

En este caso muestra la lista de valores de cada agrupación de 6 horas_

```
2022-06-01 00:00:00          [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
2022-06-01 06:00:00        [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
2022-06-01 12:00:00    [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
2022-06-01 18:00:00    [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
2022-06-02 00:00:00                        [24]
Freq: 6H, dtype: object
```

También puedes usar métodos predefinidos como `data.resample('6h').mean()`.

Para más información ir a [pandas.DataFrame.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

## Alternativa 2: Contador decimal con aproximación al piso.

Con aproximación al piso me refiero a que `0.9999` se aproxima a `0` y no a `1`. Para no importar el módulo `Math.floor()` utilizo `int()` que parece cumplir con lo mismo.

Definimos una serie sin indices temporales:

```
#data2=pd.Series(__DATO_AQUI__)
data2=pd.Series(range(len(dateIndex)))
```

`.groupby()` permite usar funciones para agrupar [ver documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), si aprovechamos eso podemos usar `int(__ROW_INDEX__/6)`.

```py
data2.groupby(lambda p: int(p/6)).mean()
```

Produce:

```
0     2.5
1     8.5
2    14.5
3    20.5
4    24.0
dtype: float64
```